# Me marca un error y no procesa el archivo

Tags: javascript, archivo, modal, botón, upload

Tengo el siguiente código que me sirve para lanzar una alerta de que no se ha cargado un archivo dentro de un modal, este funciona de manera adecuada no me genera ninguna anomalía de funcionalidad:

```js
 $('button[type="submit"].btn-primary').click(e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            var archivoInput=$("#archivoResguardoIndividual").val();
            //alert(archivo);

            if(archivoInput.length === 0){
                return swal.fire({
                    title:"Advertencia",
                    icon: "warning",
                    text:  "Debe Seleccionar un archivo",

                });
            }
```

Estoy queriendo reutilizar el mismo segmento de código para otro modal,  utilizando el mismo código salvo por el nombre de la variable

```js
 $('button[type="submit"].btn-primary').click(e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            var archivoInput=$("#archivoCargarProyectoResguardoIndividual<?=$i+1?>").val();
            //alert(archivo);

            if(archivoInput.length === 0){
                return swal.fire({
                    title:"Advertencia",
                    icon: "warning",
                    text:  "Debe Seleccionar un archivo",

                });
            }
```

y bueno en la consola me indica lo siguiente:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

y me tira la alerta de que no se ha elegido ningún archivo, aun y cuando en la consola si muestra el archivo cargado :

File {name: 'RESGUARDO_INDIVIDUAL-xxxxx_xxxxx_xxxxx-09-09-2021_(3).pdf', lastModified: 1631214496777, lastModifiedDate: Thu Sep 09 2021 14:08:16 GMT-0500 (hora de verano central),

Comment: Vecino, creo que el problema es por la variable `$i` de PHP, imagino que tienes un listado que llena los datos de la ventana modal y la variable se pierde en ese punto. Edita la pregunta para poner el listado y cómo creas la ventana modal, que espero sea una sola y no una para cada elemento.

Comment: Que comes que adivinas, efectivamente es un modal por cada botón de cargar archivo que se encuentran en un datatable, cada botón tiene su propio modal, hago esto para poder mostrar datos de usuarios desde una consulta, la consulta me sirve para generar el ciclo para ponerle numero a cada modal y variables que se relacionan con un usuario en particular.

Comment: Si no lo hago asi, los modales me muestran todos ya sea el primer o el ultimo registro de la consulta, lo que vuelve completamente inútil este proceso,  tengo la opción de enviar los datos del usuario desde el botón a un solo modal, pero sinceramente no me gusta mucho ese método, pero si no me queda de otra...

Comment: Lo ideal es usar una sola ventana modal y, de acuerdo al botón, llenar con los datos de la fila, probablemente no te gusta el método, pero es menos HTML y se puede tener mucho mejor control. De cualquier forma, edita la pregunta para agregar un ejemplo de ventana modal y decirte cómo obtener el campo de archivo para validar.

Comment: Ok Vecino entonces creo que tendré que revisar la consulta que rellena el modal, para ver si ahí traigo todos los datos que necesito para llenar el modal desde el botón  creo que es mas fácil así como lo comentas ya que en otra sección del sistema solo habré un modal, y el código expuesto funciona perfectamente, es compresible que quizás donde truena sea por la $i de PHP aunque se me hace raro por carga el nombre del archivo tal cual según la consola.  reviso y te aviso si no para borrar esta pregunta.  Saludos y buen finde!!.

Comment: ya revise la consulta sin problema traigo los datos que necesito, así que procedo a editar el código  para que cargue todos los valores desde el botón al modal, y solo preocuparme por la visualización , validación y carga del archivo dentro del modal.  GRacie!!!